# Deep merging two Immutable maps while ignoring nested arrays

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

```js
const map1 = Immutable.Map({ a: { x: 1, z: 1, y: 1, values: [1, 2, 3] } });
const map2 = Immutable.Map({ a: { x: 2, values: [4, 5, 6] } });

const map3 = map1.mergeDeep(map2)

// Output I want is:
// { a: { x: 2, z: 1, y: 1 values: [4, 5, 6] } }
```

Let's say I have two maps. One of the maps is a partial object of the other, doesn't necessarily contain all the same properties. I want to merge them, including the nested objects, but not merge the arrays. So as you can see above, it's updated the properties that exist in both maps, kept the old properties that don't exist in the new second map, and only used the latest map array rather than merging them into [1,2,3,4,5,6]. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This question seems related to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605528/losing-properties-when-using-mergedeep-of-immutable-js) stackoverflow post. As stated there using [**`fromJS`**](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) instead of [**`Map`**](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) gives the desired result. In addition [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33749406/10353987) answer does a good job explaining the difference between the two. Please refer to and run the snippet below for a working example:

```js
const map1 = Immutable.fromJS({ a: { x: 1, z: 1, y: 1, values: [1, 2, 3] } });
const map2 = Immutable.fromJS({ a: { x: 2, values: [4, 5, 6] } });

const map3 = map1.mergeDeep(map2)

console.log(map3)

// Output I want is:
// { a: { x: 2, z: 1, y: 1 values: [4, 5, 6] } }

/* And this snippet results in:
{
  "a": {
    "x": 2,
    "z": 1,
    "y": 1,
    "values": [
      4,
      5,
      6
    ]
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.js" integrity="sha512-9XVMKQr4ymAxO4jZVbEM2eq01aGlTY4bMlWyQh+KcQWprFkWu5KpOcDOa3RLFZc586QHihZPd1b8XzXqweRxIQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: if you run this you'll see values has length 6, I want the array to be replaced by [4,5,6], not merged

Comment: @GregM I'm confused, that's exactly what you get if you run the snippet, the values array is replaced by [4,5,6]. Are you using some other version of immutable?

Answer (score 0):

You did not state the immutable.js version you used, but the way you asked, it is probably 4.0.0-rc12. The mergeDeep function of Immutable.js version 3.8.x did what you want; It replaced arrays instead of merging them. That's why @etarhan's answer works but does not for you.

There is no "nice" solution. The [`mergeDeepWith`](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mergeDeepWith) function let's you define a merger function, but sadly the merger is only triggered on conflicts - so it does not help you either. All you can do is walk the object manually or upgrade immutable.js.

Also note that `Immutable.Map({ a: { x: 1, z: 1, y: 1, values: [1, 2, 3] } });` does only convert the input shallowly. The array of `values` stays an *array*. That is often undesired, you would want to have an Immutable.List instead of an array. To do so, use `fromJS`, which converts depply.

I'll bring this up on the slack channel, IMO there should be the possbility to call the merger on collections too.

Something similar to this might do the job:

```js
const map1 = Immutable.fromJS({ a: { x: 'one', z: 'old', y: 'old', values: [1, 2, 3] } });
const map2 = Immutable.fromJS({ a: { x: 'two', v: 'new', values: [4, 5, 6] } });


function mergeStuff(a, b, path = '') {
  return a.withMutations(map => {
    for(key of b.keys()) {
      map.update(key, (val) => {
        console.log('updating', path + key, val, b.get(key));
        if(Immutable.isKeyed(val)) {
          return mergeStuff(val, b.get(key), key + '.');
        }
        return b.get(key, val);
      });
    }
  });
}

const map3 = mergeStuff(map1, map2);

console.log('result:');
console.log(map3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/4.0.0-rc.12/immutable.js"></script>
```